# Smooth animation Swing concurrency

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I have a panel that shows a grid , for example a 6 x 7. The grid is made with Jpanels , each Jpanel have a mouseListener , when a cell of the grid is pressed the correspondent Jpanel should change it's color.
I made an animation that when i click on a specific panel ( a specific cell of the grid i.e (1,1)) it will change every other cell color in the selected column ,it works but not smooth as wanted ,there is my code :

each Grid cell have this method :

```
        @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                        Thread play = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                try {

                                    game.setData( column);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        play.start();
            }
```

game.setdata(column) method is used to store the "used" columns , after storing the informations it will update the panel , the way it does it's simple , for each row in the selected column the new color is set:

```
    Runnable a = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(int i =0 ; i <row; ++i){
                final int position = i;

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                panel.getRow(position).setColor(finalColor);        
                        }           
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    }


        }

    };


    Thread painter= new Thread(a);
    painter.start();

    while(painter.isAlive()){
        donePainting = false;
    }

    donePainting = true;
}
```

this piece of code :

```
   while(painter.isAlive()){
        donePainting = false;
    }

    donePainting = true;
```

is used to wait until the drawing is finished.
How can i make the animation smoother ?

Comment: 1. there can be endless numbers of threads, invoked from every `mousePressed` ->
                        `Thread play = new Thread(new Runnable() {`


2. use `Swing Timer` instead of  `Runnable#Thread`, to test inside `mousePressed` for `SwingTimer.isRunning`, if it runs, then to call `SwingTimer.restart`, note required local variable for `Swing Timer`

3. `Thread.sleep(200);` inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` lock an EDT, for more info to read Oracle trail `Concurency in Swing`, 4. by using `Swing Timer` is `Thread.sleep(200);` useless

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local variables

Comment: Consider using a Swing `Timer` instead of all the `Thread`s